# How to exclude local users from PAM auto mount?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pam, sssd

I'm using sssd and pam to allow people to log in via AD and automatically mount NFS shares. It works fine, but when I try to login as a local user like root, the auto-mount process fails and it takes more than 1 minute to log in.

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.

How can I exclude certain users from the PAM mount process?

Comment: pam_mount has a sophistocated configuratoin ased on XML - https://man.archlinux.org/man/pam_mount.conf.5 - including the ability to define behaviours for specific users and groups (and a 'not' operator)

Comment: ok i foiund the option "pgroup" to specify a group, that works. what if i want to wait for vpn to connect before mounting?

Comment: Don't use automount.

Comment: i definitely need automount thats not an option,inst there a way to wait for VPN connection or something?

Comment: I see no reason for a REQUIREMENT to use automount (you didn't state what your objective was, only that you wanted to use automount to achieve it) and you didn't state in your post that there was a dependency on a VPN link. Suggest you start again with a statement of your requirements (not the means by which you want to achieve them), details of the constraints and the config you currently have.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is the XY problem

Comment: ......................... thanks a lot